# How to apply different css styles to two different form elements on the same page?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am trying to create a web page with a search bar that has it's own styling at the top and then a form later on in the page using django and crispy forms. Currently, the styling for my search bar applies to the styling for my form, and I don't want that. I would like to use bootstrap crispy forms to style the form and my own custom css to style the search bar. (The search bar is coded as a form with input.)

I have tried reordering the links in the head of my html, bootstrap first, search bar second, and the other way around, and it didn't affect anything rather than screw up the positioning of my search bar. I have tried wrapping both forms in divs with seperate ids and seperate classes, and it also didn't work. I have tried giving an id to my custom search bar form. I am aware of CSS Specificity.

I'm not sure how to make it happen so that I can completely separate the two. Help is appreciated.

relevant html:

```
<head>
        ...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/main.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/search_bar.css' %}" />
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/noscript.css' %}" /></noscript>    
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div class="searchbar">
        <form action="">
            <input type="search">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </form>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="spotlight">
        <form action ="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% crispy form %}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

And the custom css file I'm trying to only apply to the search bar:

```
.searchbar form {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transition: all 1s !important;
    background: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 4px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
}
.searchbar input{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;;
    height: 42.5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.searchbar .fa{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 42.5px;
    height: 42.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #07051a;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.searchbar form:hover{
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.searchbar form:hover input{
    display: block;
    color: black;
}

.searchbar form:hover .fa{
    background: pink;
    color: white;
}
```

EDIT: This is what I'd like the final UI to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t79F.png

Comment: Do you have an image of how you would like the final outcome? That would help to figure out exactly what are you intending to accomplish.

Comment: this is what ID or CLASS are made for ;)

Comment: @AleDP I'd like it to look like https://i.imgur.com/82g36KY.png Currently, the form with hostname and such centers and opens on hover like the searchbar.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I tried using ID and CLASS, they didn't work for me. If they are indeed the way to go, I'd need clarification on how to use them so they'd work, because what I tried, didn't.

Comment: Hello Eenna, when you inspect the searchbar input do you see any classes applied to it? Can you try to add a class to it. I suspect that it could be a specificity issue what is causing this. 

Assuming that your css links are properly routed. Did you tested it doing bold changes as borders or background colors just to be sure they are working?

Comment: @AleDP I added a class to the input and changed the "input" selector in my css to it, and it helped solve the problem! Thank you for that! Before, I did try changing the bg colour, font colour, etc and it was changing it for both search and form. When I inspected, I saw other classes that were trying to style the input, with my css at the very top, then main.css then _reboot.scss (from bootstrap). Thank you so so much for your help though!

Comment: Glad to help you :) Good luck with the rest of your project!